# How to unset a specific session variable after 30 minutes

Tags: php, sql

It is for an e-commerce platform, people can buy unique piece item.

To prevent multiple people from buying the same item at the same time, when someone click Add to cart, the item is booked for this person for 30 minutes and the product id goes to database.
A cron job runs every minute and deletes booked items older than 30 minutes.

But for the person that added the item to his cart, all the cart's information are stored in his `SESSION["cart"]` variable, and plainly, this variable lasts longer than 30 minutes...

So my question is :

- how can I unset the person's `SESSION["cart"]` 30 minutes after he clicked on Add to cart, if he didnt complete his order ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the time that user clicked on `Add to cart` in `$_SESSION`.

Ex:

```
$_SESSION['clicked_time']=time();
```

Then check if `current_time - $_SESSION['clicked_time']` is greter than 30 minutes or not.
this part should execute when user come back to complete order.